# Calculating the reach of a planet's umbra

Tags: astronomy, geometric-optics, planets

I'm trying to calculate how far behind a planet its umbra reaches. So far in my search of the topics on google I have only found pages about how to calculate the size or time of moon eclipse.

But it's not what I'm interested in. To describe what I'm in, imagine a cone, being a planet's umbra, which base is centered in the planet's center. Now what I want is how far from the planet's center is the tip of that cone. And I want the equation that is dependent of the planet's radius $r$, the star's radius $R$ and the distance $d$ from that star to the planet.

I know it may be a simple math here, but so far I don't know how to approach the problem :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important first step is to draw a picture
of the star, the planet and some light rays.

- $R$ is the radius of the star
- $r$ is the radius of the planet
- $d$ is the distance between star and planet
- $x$ is the length of the planet's umbra (shaded in gray)

[image]

(To make the geometry easier, I have drawn star and planet as flat disks
instead of as round spheres. Because $d\gg R$ and $d\gg r$ this 
simplification will cause only a small error in the final result.)

Now consider the red triangle and apply the [intercept thorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) to it.
You get
$$\frac{R}{r}=\frac{d+x}{x}$$

I leave it to you to solve this equation for $x$.

Comment: Got it! I have $x = \frac{rx}{R-r}$. Sorry I reply in the comments, but I have got not enough reputation points to upvote your reply :).

Comment: @Felix.leg On the right side you probably mean $d$, not $x$.

Answer (score 1):

One should rather consider a cone, ***based on the star***, and containing the planet.

The radius of that cone decreases linearly from the star's radius, $R$ to the planet's radius, $r$, over a distance (along the cone's axis) of $d$.

Given this rate of decrease, how much further must one travel along the axis to decrease the radius from $r$ to zero?